# Django template for loop inside <select> renders values after the select

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to use JQuery widget [Multiple select](https://github.com/crlcu/multiselect) instead of default.

As you can see, I'm trying to render select options right into `<select>` tag but, it's weird that it is being rendered after `</select>` tag. (for loop is inside this tag, not after)

EDIT:
Simly, this is in the template:

```
<tag> {% for choice in field.choices %}{{ choice }}{%endfor%} </tag>
```

but Django renders it like it was:

```
<tag></tag>  {% for choice in field.choices %}{{ choice }} {%endfor%}
```

This is rendered:

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
            <select name="from[]" id="multiselect" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
</select> # options are render after this tag

<option value="97">Slovak</option>
<option value="98">Russian</option>
<option value="99">Magyar</option>
<option value="100">English</option>
<option value="101">Croatian</option>
<option value="102">Spanish</option>
<option value="103">Dutch</option>
<option value="104">Estonian</option>
<option value="105">French</option>
<option value="106">DSADSA</option> etc....
```

This is the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block head %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/scripts/multiselect.min.js" %}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#multiselect').multiselect();
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Become a translator</h1>
    <form id="user_form" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ register_as_translator_form | crispy }}
            <button class="accordion" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">Register</button>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <select name="from[]" id="multiselect" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
                {% for choice in register_as_translator_form.languages %}
                    {{ choice }}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightAll" class="btn btn-block"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightSelected" class="btn btn-block"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftSelected" class="btn btn-block"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftAll" class="btn btn-block"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <select name="to[]" id="multiselect_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Unfortunately, it renders this:**
[image]

Do you know what to do?

Comment: I doubt very much this is Django doing this. Please look at the rendered HTML source - not the interpreted DOM in the developer tools, but the raw View Source output - and post what is actually being produced.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It was probably Django (I'm not expert so I'm not sure). As Ahmed said in the answer below. Don't know if it's bug or what.. but his answer works. Now, the for cycle is being rendered inside <select>. I made some changes and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could happen if `register_as_translator_form.languages` return string list, try this way:

```
    <select name="from[]" id="multiselect" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
        {% for choice in register_as_translator_form.languages %}
            <option value="{{ choice }}">{{ choice }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks ahmed, this seems to work. But there is a little problem. It seems that one of the choices is <select> tag or something. I've put <p>START</p> YOUR CODE INSIDE SELECT TAG <p>STOP</p> to see what choices are rendered and this is the result. It seems that the first option is tag. https://ghostbin.com/paste/rx8cx

Comment: @Milano i don't know what `register_as_translator_form.languages` return, but you can do some filtering in the view, and pass only language data to your view

Comment: I figured it out, I've just changed it to for value,text in register_as_translator_form.languages.field.choices and value = "{{ value }}">{{ key}}... and it works. Thanks!